# Strange git error

Tags: windows, git, windows-8, dropbox, msysgit

What I'm trying to do is, to get local clone of dropbox project, make changes then push to this project.

My PC Specs are: Os Win 8 X64, [Git-1.7.11](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list)

I did following steps:

1. Copied original project files into Dropbox folder
2. Initialized git repo in project directory which located in local file system, Dropbox folder
3. Then cloned this directory by typing `git clone absolute/path/to/the/folder`
4. Made some changes to the files just for testing, committed.. all gone well
5. When I tried to push this by typing `git push origin master` getting this error message

[image]

Raw TXT looks like that

```
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 322 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare reposit
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree incon
ent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to
h
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error:
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variabl

remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing

remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless y
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in

remote: error: other way.
remote: error:
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour,

remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse
To F:\Cloud\Dropbox\Web Server\pcand.me
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'F:\Cloud\Dropbox\Web Server\pcand.me'
```

Tried to fully uninstall with cleaning traces and reinstall 3 times, did steps above 2-3 times. Nothing helped

## What am I missing?

Comment: "By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare reposit is denied" How did you init the new repo?

Comment: @PeeHaa Right Click inside folder-> Git Init (This command created hidden .git folder) Then appended all files inside this folder.

Comment: Can you try `git init --bare` and try again?

Comment: @PeeHaa all steps again? or just to do this in dropbox project folder?

Comment: @PeeHaa `git init --bare` it must be first step?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16269/discussion-between-epic-syntax-and-peehaa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it's not a good idea to push to a non-bare repository.

What I'd do is:

Create an empty directory "/path/to/bare/repository"
Enter that directory and do a

```
git init --bare
```

This will initialize a git structure that is safe to push into. Don't put any files from your dropbox folder there.

Create an empty directory "/path/to/working/folder"

Copy the dropbox files there, enter the directory and type the following commands

```
git init
git remote add origin /path/to/bare/repository
git commit -a -m 'Initial commit'
git push origin master
```

The `git init` command doesn't have the `--bare` parameter, so this will be a working folder where you can see your files. After you have pushed the files to the "origin" repository, check the contents of the bare repository. You won't find any readable files there, only your git index.

Comment: Don't get really. Can you do a favor for me and enter to my PC via teamviewer?

Comment: @epic_syntax: The problem with pushing to a non-bare repo is that it doesn't update the working directory, so stuff gets all out of whack.  Basically, the point of the answer is, have two repos.  One's bare, and that's where you push changes to.  The other has a working directory (ie: not bare), and you go there and *pull* from the bare repo to get the changes more safely.

Comment: @cHao I can't get "You won't find any readable files there, only your git index." Yes I did it all. Now, if someone will pull from non-readable folder, he will get normal content?

Comment: @epic_syntax: What that means is "there's nothing to see here; move along".  The directory's still readable, and writable, and will contain any commits you push to it.  It just doesn't have a corresponding working directory to update.  When someone pulls from it, their git will effectively retrieve your changes and replay them on its own repo, and will update its own working directory accordingly.  So yeah, they'll see everything as normal.

Comment: @cHao as far as I understand, the git folder and the working directory must be in seperate folders? And how main project will be updated then?

Comment: @cHao please visit http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16269/discussion-between-epic-syntax-and-peehaa

Comment: If you are the only user and don't need a backup, one repository is fine. If you want to backup your data or if you want to share your data, you require a 2nd repository, where you can only "push" or "fetch". This one is initialized with the keyword 'bare' which marks it as safe.

Just think what'd happen, if you'd modify files in your local repository. Your HEAD is the master branch, but you didn't commit your changes yet. If now someone moved the master branch, your uncommitted changes would be either lost or in an unpredictable state.